# Bluetooth keyboard not showing the PIN necessary to complete pairing?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

The Bluetooth keyboard on Asus T300 Chi has been disconnected and I can't seem to get it to connect (pair) again. It's asking for a PIN that should be showing so you can enter it on the keyboard to complete the pairing process but it never shows the PIN. I have tried:

- Rebooting the system
- Tried Random PINs that matched on the tablet and the keyboard.
- Uninstalled and installed the Bluetooth drivers.
- 0000
- Searched on Asus forums but no with no luck.

Comment: Did you try 0000 ?

Comment: Yes I've tried that too.

Comment: The usual process for keyboards is to select any PIN and then type that in on the keyboard, confirming it with Enter.

Answer (score 5):

Symple solution:

- scan for keyboard
- press connect
- use screen keyboard to type a code like 1234
- press connect
- now type on keyboard same code 1234
- Press ENTER

done

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem and there is no pin for your keyboard you have to go to that old control panel and remove your keyboard from there

If its still there and then after restarting go to the same page on your control panel and add a device then hold your keyboard power button for 5 seconds until your system finds it then click on it and click next it will ask for a pin but under that box it has written try a pass code on your keyboard click on it and then type that pass code on your keyboard and then press enter - it will be done